# How to expose foreign key column in the entity in TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

I have failed to expose the foreign key column in the entity which I feel weird to not be able to.

If I am not eager loading the relation, at least I should be able to to see the `imageId` to have some clue of the existence of the relation. so when I do a `userRepository.findOne({email: emailaddress})`, even I know that I can not `eager load` the image this way. But at least I could see the `imageId`.

```
@Column('datetime', { nullable: true, name: 'last_login' })
lastLogin: string;

@OneToOne(() => UserSetting)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'setting_id' })
setting: UserSetting;

@OneToOne(() => UserImage, { onDelete: 'SET NULL' })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'image_id' })
image: UserImage;

imageUrl: { preview: string, thumbnail: string };

@OneToMany(() => Contact, contact => contact.user)
contacts: Contact[];

@OneToMany(() => Notification, notification => notification.user)
notifications: Notification[];
```

As you can see, there is no `imageId` defined. I tried to put it like this. The database just cannot be synced up and it wiped out all my image data too.

```
@Column({name: 'image_id' })
imageId: string;

@OneToOne(() => UserImage, { onDelete: 'SET NULL' })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'image_id' })
image: UserImage;
```

Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `User Entity` should look like this:

```
@Column({ nullable: true })
imageId: string;

@OneToOne(() => UserImage, userImage=> userImage.user, { onDelete: 'SET NULL' })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'image_id' })
image: UserImage;
```

and in your `UserImage Entity`:

```
@OneToOne(() => User, user=> user.image)
user: User;
```

Comment: Tried that. It breaks the database. imageId should add {name:  'image_id'} as well right?

Comment: You are right. I missed the nullable: true part. But after adding it, image id data are gone.

Comment: Maybe you should set the default value as well.

Comment: For the record, this is when creating the entity. Not for modifying it. If you are still running on the auto-migrate mode, adding the foreign key column will wipe out the whole foreign key column data.